# Extracting JSON content from CDATA in SOAP Response

Tags: soapui, cdata, web-api-testing

I am working on SoapUI where I have a Soap request which takes input in Json String format and after the processing I get a Soap Response in XML with JSON format enclosed in CDATA.

I am trying to extract the data from Soap Response using the below code but I get error "Content is not allowed in prolog"

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper
import groovy.xml.Namespace

respXmlHolder = new XmlHolder(messageExchange.getResponseContentAsXml())
respXmlHolder.declareNamespace("ns1","http://tempuri.org/")
CDATAXml = respXmlHolder.getNodeValue("//ns1:ReportResult")
log.info(CDATAXml)


def data = new XmlParser().parseText(CDATAXml).Rpt
log info "data.findAll{it.'Name'}.size()"
```

The Soap Response looks this way as shown below:

```
<ReportResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <ReportResult><![CDATA[{
  "Report": [
    {
      "Name": "ABC",
      "Number": "123",
      "Type": "XYZ",
      "Desc": "EFGH",
      "Group Name": "Name123",
      "Group Number": "123",
      "End Date": "12/30/2014",
      "Due Date": "04/15/2015",
      "Completion Date": null,
      "Status": "Status1",
      "Received Date": "",
      "Delivery Date": "",
      "Location": "",
      "Role": "",
     },
     {
      "Name": "EFG",
       "Number": "123",
      "Type": "XYZ",
      "Desc": "EFGH",
      "Group Name": "Name123",
      "Group Number": "123",
      "End Date": "12/30/2014",
      "Due Date": "04/15/2015",
      "Completion Date": null,
      "Status": "Status1",
      "Received Date": "",
      "Delivery Date": "",
      "Location": "",
      "Role": "Manager",
     }
    ]
} ]]></ReportResult>
  </ReportResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: You are trying to get `Result` using xpath, but where is it in the xml? You can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716317/script-assertion-for-json-response/36717797#36717797) similar example to extract json.

Comment: The example you mentioned has data not enclosed in CDATA tried extracting but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rao note in the comments, you're using `//ns1:Result` as an *XPath* however this node doesn't exist in your response. Anyway as an alternative instead of use and `XmlHolder`, I purpose to use first `XmlSlurper` to parse the SOAP and get the `CDATA` node, and then `JSonSlurper` to parse the *JSON* contained in `CDATA` and get the desired values (in your case seems that you're looking for `Name` value attribute), see the below example:

```java
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def soapResponse = '''<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
<ReportResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <ReportResult><![CDATA[{
  "Report": [
    {
      "Name": "ABC",
      "Number": "123",
      "Type": "XYZ",
      "Desc": "EFGH",
      "Group Name": "Name123",
      "Group Number": "123",
      "End Date": "12/30/2014",
      "Due Date": "04/15/2015",
      "Completion Date": null,
      "Status": "Status1",
      "Received Date": "",
      "Delivery Date": "",
      "Location": "",
      "Role": "",
     },
     {
      "Name": "EFG",
       "Number": "123",
      "Type": "XYZ",
      "Desc": "EFGH",
      "Group Name": "Name123",
      "Group Number": "123",
      "End Date": "12/30/2014",
      "Due Date": "04/15/2015",
      "Completion Date": null,
      "Status": "Status1",
      "Received Date": "",
      "Delivery Date": "",
      "Location": "",
      "Role": "Manager",
     }
    ]
} ]]></ReportResult>
  </ReportResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>'''

// parse the soap
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(soapResponse)
// get cdata node
def reportCDATA = xml.'**'.findAll{ it.name() == 'ReportResult' }
def jsonTxt = reportCDATA.pop().toString()
// parse CDATA value as JSON
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonTxt)
// get the Name attribute values
def names = json.Report.collect { it.Name }
names.each { log.info it }
```

If as you comment, instead of `"Name"` value of your *JSON* you want to get `"Completion Date"` you can do it as:

```
def completionDates = json.Report.collect { it."Completion Date"}
```

Or if looks more clear:

```
def completionDates = json.Report.collect { it[Completion Date] }
```

Take in account that in your sample the `Report` array contain two objects which both has `null` as value for `"Completion Date"`. So using your *JSON* sample `def completionDates` will be `[null, null]`.

Hope it helps,

Comment: I am getting empty result for the below mentioned code :

    def names = json.Report.collect { it.Name }
    names.each { log.info it }

In case if I want to extract value for Completion date I have to mention this way it."Completion Date"  ??

Comment: If you get empty result is surely because your input data differs from the data in the example, check for the path correctness in `XmlSlurper` and `JsonSlurper`. To get the `"Completion date"` check the updated response `:)`

Comment: Yes I have tried the below 
    def Dates = json.Report.collect { it."Completion date"}
I get no result in the Script Assertion 

Actually I have more than 100 objects in the Report array.

Comment: Agree with @albciff, data presented in the question does not have data for `Completion Date`. For example if you take `Due Date`, dates are listed which can seen in the [screen shot](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=17554526615670735162). More over, SDhwaj is using incorrect property name i.e., using `Completion date` instead of `Completion Date`. Please try correcting it.

Comment: Looks a copy paste issue for the incorrect case. The first comment has wrong case and @albciff used incorrect case in the provided script and is copied by the other or vice- versa.

Comment: @Rao you're right again, thanks `: )`... mobile is not the good way to answer haha.

Comment: I have tried the above mentioned for data which exists I do not get any result.

    def GrpNum = json.Report.collect{it."Group Number"}

    GrpNum.each{
     log.info it
    }